# Targeted autogeneration of abc.feature.cs file in SpecFlow

Tags: specflow

we have set of feature file which have scenarios shared between  mid-tier  and UI using tags ( @services , @UI ) 
Now when i give this feature file to Specflow . it generates the test-runner wiring  for whole feature file.. including @services scenarios
which is useless as we don;t implement them at UI level.

So my question ..is there a way to tell Specflow  that only auto-generate test-runner wiring code for scenarios which are tagged with @UI ..?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious answer of splitting your feature file into UI.feature and Services.feature, then no. There is no way of getting generating multiple .feature.cs files from a single .feature.

However can I suggest that this mixing of steps is indicative that your specifications are crossing domains, which usually suggests that they are might be very technical instead of behaviour driven.

Comment: Yeah,Splitting would have made our life much easier but then we would have had 2 sets of feature file to verify same info with lot of step duplication. its just that initial automation was done using cucumber-JVM at midtier level and now we are introducing Specflow at UI level....the "given" and "when" steps between ui and servers scenario are same,only "then" changes. and no they are not technical,they still represent behavior

Comment: Good News! There isn't any step duplication as steps are basically global.